# MySQL query to select records which don't have a particular status, data having same id with multiple statuses

Tags: mysql, sql

#### Sample Data:

[image]

Please have a look on the above data. I want MySQL **query to get the distinct records which don't have status 1 or 4**

**Note:** records are having same id with multiple statuses.

#### Desired Response:

[image]

Please somebody help me !!!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hello Sampath, according to your data 27 have 2 and 3 so it should be shown in resultset, isn't it?

Comment: Hello Anirudha, i want 28, 30 in the result set.

Comment: query that should return the id which do not have status 1 and 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using left outer join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.user_id
FROM your_table t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN your_table t2
ON t1.user_id     = t2.user_id
AND t2.status    IN (1, 4)
WHERE t2.user_id IS NULL;
```

## Using Simple subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_Id
FROM your_table
WHERE user_id NOT IN
  (SELECT user_id FROM your_table t2 WHERE status IN (1, 4)
  );
```

## Using correlated subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM your_table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
  FROM your_table t2
  WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id
  AND t2.status   IN (1, 4)
  );
```

<sub>P.S.: you can use `group by user_id` instead of using `distinct`</sub>

Comment: Where sub queries should not be aliased, minus is not a mysql verb, first not should be removed.

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks for the comment. I had my doubt about MINUS, but got a bit lazy. :)

Comment: Thanks for the query. @GurwinderSingh: I've a very large set of data like around 20 crore records. I want a more optimized query.

Comment: @Sampath The first two queries are as fast as they get. Problem will arise when you don't have proper indexes in place.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh: I've index on status. I ran all above 3 queries and verified network traffic. the second one(Simple query) is working better than other two queries. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    user_id
FROM
    table_name
WHERE
    STATUS IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            status
        FROM
            table_name
        WHERE
            status != 1
        AND status != 4
    ) st;
```

Comment: We need to apply filter on status. Not user_id.

Comment: @Joseph Mwema test should be on status?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    user_id
FROM
    test
WHERE
    test.`status` NOT IN (1, 4)
GROUP BY
    user_id
```

Comment: The above query doesn't work in case data has multiple records with same user_id's and statuses.

Answer (score 0):

**given**

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(id int, status int);
truncate table t;
insert into t values
(1,1),(1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,4),(3,3);
```

**this**

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select s.id
    -> from
    -> (
    -> select id,
    -> sum(case when status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) OneExists,
    -> sum(case when status = 4 then 1 else 0 end) fourexists
    -> from t
    -> group by id
    -> ) s
    -> where s.OneExists = 0 or s.fourexists = 0
    -> ;
```

**Result**

```
    +------+
    | id   |
    +------+
    |    1 |
    |    2 |
    +------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```